# React - navigate to section from other link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I have navigation in my app, one link has got attr `to='/'` and I have method onClick that is taking me to section `about`. When I am on main Page `'/'` it works, but when I am on different pages nav works but only returning me to main page but I want also to take me to section. I can do this after second click. How can i solve this issue ?

```
<li>
    <NavLink to="/" activeClassName={window.pageYOffset > this.scroll && "active-main"} className="link-left" onClick={this.goToAbout}>
        O Nas
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

Method:

```
goToAbout = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, this.scroll);
  };
```

ComponentDidMount:

```
this.aboutUs = document.getElementById("aboutUs");
this.scroll = this.aboutUs.offsetTop - 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior so your link won't go to "/" anymore, only scrolls

```
    goToAbout = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, this.scroll);
    };
```

Comment: Better, but I can't onClick change the page and navigate to section ?

Comment: So you want to change the page and scroll down to that section in the new page? Why don't use anchors? navigating to /newpage#sectionid will navigate and scroll without having to use js

Comment: On anchors it reloads me page

Comment: Do you have an example of your intended behavior?

Comment: I want exacly what anchor does but without refreshing the page.

Comment: I'm using js because I need to change classes depends on scroll position

Comment: Ok, then your link shouldn't be "/", instead you should use a hash. Using to="#sectionid" will scroll without refreshing.

Comment: It changes site without refresh but on any click it doesn't move to section

Comment: Look this link: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394